# Producing self-contained source?

Tags: macros, bibtex

Is there a way (terminal command?) to take a TeX file, possibly with externally linked macros, bibstyle files, bibTeX source, etc., and automatically produce a single, self-contained TeX file? For example, I could generate the bbl file, copy and paste the entries there and add to the source, but it gets tedious. Anyone solve this problem?

Comment: just stick bib files bst files and anything else you need at the start of the tex document, in `filecontents` environemnts.

Comment: @HenriMenke Not really a duplicate. This question rather needs that plus one or more of the linked bibliography strategies to create a document-specific `.bib` etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you elaborate on your suggestion? So if I have a file with macros stored in some central directory (so as to avoid duplication in the working directory, and also clutter in the document), and I want to include that in a document I'm currently working on, how would I use filecontents? I looked at the documentation for the package but couldn't figure out how it would work for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need a package, I'll post an example

Answer (score 1):

This document bundles up a local latex package and a local bibtex database as a single file, usimg `filecontents`, producing

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{mypackage.sty}
\def\zzzz{Hello}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{zzz.bib}
@article{zz99,
    title={something},
    author={M. Eee and Y. Ouoo},
    journal={TugBoat},
    volume={14},
    number={2},
    pages={200--100},
    year={1884},
    publisher={example.org}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}

\zzzz, \cite{zz99}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{zzz}

\end{document}
```